# Sudo - is there a command to check if I have sudo and/or how much time is left?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

(Originally posted on Stack Overflow).  They suggested I try here instead.  Here's the original post:

- [Sudo - is there a command to check if I have sudo and/or how much time is left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858208/sudo-is-there-a-command-to-check-if-i-have-sudo-and-or-how-much-time-is-left)

See title. I want a command that lets me query sudo. Ideally, it would return success if I still have sudo and false if sudo has expired. Getting the time left might also be useful (although if I was concerned I could just do `sudo -v` to revalidate.) Oh and it shouldn't have to ask for a password.

The closest thing I've found is `sudo -n true`, but the `-n` option is only present on my Centos 5 machine at work. `-n` fails if it has to ask for a password. Is there any other way to get this functionality? Assume I don't actually have root on all the machines I work with, so I can't install new versions of sudo to my liking.

For what it's worth I'm doing this so I can get my prompt to indicate sudo status. I like knowing which terminals are actively sudo-able. I also have a prompt that changes colors when I'm root, but I don't use root very often so that's of limited use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `-n` option is available in newer versions of `sudo`, but as you stated that's not an option.  There's no real way to do what you're looking for short of just trying `sudo` and seeing if it comes back with a prompt for a password.  If your concern is you want a visual indication, why not start do `sudo /bin/bash` to start a root bash session?  Note that this is insecure, but it's also somewhat insecure if someone realizes your prompt changes on sudo.

Comment: +1 for the security ramifications of a visual indicator!

Comment: That part hadn't occurred to me.  What I'm hoping the indicator does is remind me to run sudo -K, instead of forgetting I left sudo active and leaving some potentially dangerous terminals open.  Not that I often forget to lock my screen, but I like the extra insurance.

Comment: At the moment I'm leaning toward checking sudo -V, and if it's sufficiently new enough to have -n, checking -n to get the notification.  Seems like it shouldn't break anything anywhere.

Comment: @valadil: It occurs to me that a subtle indicator wouldn't introduce too much security risk. Turn on underlining for the username in the prompt, for example.

Comment: @Dennis: Exactly.  I wasn't going to change my prompt into "OMG_YOU_HAVE_SUDO_NOW!_user@host" or something like that.  I'd probably just change the color a little.  I don't expect anybody to know what that means unless they sit down and get intimate with my .bashrc.

Comment: For an user that does have none configuration through in `sudoers`  - therefore is impossible use `sudo` - the execution of `sudo -n <command>` **always** prints in the terminal the `sudo: a password is required` message. So be careful with this approach

Answer (score 32):

I know this is a really old question but here is I did in a script today. Assuming that being sudo means being able to run any command as sudo (or, at least, uptime)

```
CAN_I_RUN_SUDO=$(sudo -n uptime 2>&1 | grep "load" | wc -l)
if [ ${CAN_I_RUN_SUDO} -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "I can run the sudo command"
else
    echo "I can't run the Sudo command"
fi
```

However, if your user has restrictions in the `visudo`, this check will not be enough, e.g., if your user can only use the make command. Try running some command that you know will work.

You may add the filter `grep -v Sorry`, e.g.:

```
$(sudo -n uptime 2>&1 | grep "load" | grep -v Sorry | wc -l)
```

for avoiding those false positives.

Comment: For an user that does have none configuration through in `sudoers`  - therefore is impossible use `sudo` - the execution of `sudo -n <command>` **always** prints in the terminal the `sudo: a password is required` message. So be careful with this approach - therefore `$(sudo -n uptime 2>&1 | grep "load" | wc -l)` **always** is going to return `0`.

This approach is really valuable if user can use `sudo` and the `timeout` is still valid - it returns `1`

Answer (score 3):

To simplify the answer given by @wags007

```
if sudo -n true
then
  sudo id
else
  echo "sorry, but did not want to bother you"
fi
```

However, if in your https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html configuration you have `defaults mail_badpass` there will be a mail sent for every test that results in false (would have prompted). To avoid such nuisance change that part of your sudoers file to

```
Defaults       mail_badpass
Defaults!      /bin/true !mail_badpass
```

As a result security alert mails are send for all commands except /bin/true. Well yes, somebody could now try to brute force a password by calling `sudo true` an unlimited number of times without any security alert mail being sent.

Note: Always use `visudo` instead of your favorite editor to edit the sudoers file. Failing to do so you risk being locked out.

Answer (score 1):

The command below will show a colored indication that you have sudo granted, so you remember to do a `sudo -k` before going away from the machine. It is useful also on non colored terminals.

As we can have sudo active and inactive on different terminal sessions, I created this that you can put at the end of your ~/.bashrc

```
function FUNCpromptCommand () { 
    sudo -n uptime 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
  local bSudoOn=`if(($?==0));then echo true; else echo false; fi`

    history -a; # append to history at each command issued!!!
    local width=`tput cols`;
    local half=$((width/2))
    local dt="[EndAt:`date +"%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S.%N"`]";
  if $bSudoOn; then dt="!!!SUDO!!!$dt"; fi
    local sizeDtHalf=$((${#dt}/2))
    #printf "%-${width}s" $dt |sed 's" "="g'; 
    echo
    output=`printf "%*s%*s" $((half+sizeDtHalf)) "$dt" $((half-sizeDtHalf)) "" |sed 's" "="g';`

    local colorLightRed="\e[1;31m"
  local colorNoColor="\e[0m"
    if $bSudoOn; then
        echo -e "${colorLightRed}${output}${colorNoColor}"
    else
        echo -e "${output}"
    fi
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=FUNCpromptCommand
```

At terminal type `bash` to test it. It will also add a whole line each time you execute a command, that has the information of the time the last command ended, so you can go lunch and know when the last command ended :).

You can play with this code to fit your needs. There is the PS1 variable also (that is the actual small prompt single line), but I think it is better to not mess with it.

PS.: for OS-X, look for the comment below by @nwinkler.

Comment: Checking the exit code of `sudo -n` does not seem to work on OS X. See my question here: http://superuser.com/questions/902826/why-does-sudo-n-on-mac-os-x-always-return-0

Comment: well, the test I propose is `sudo -n`, do you believe there could have any other test that could be used to determine if user has sudo access active? or maybe OS-X requires some update? I never used OS-X btw.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of OS X. It's possible that `sudo -n` on BSD (which OS X is based on) has a different behavior than the GNU version. I just added my comment to let people know that this version of the check does not seem to work on OS X. I have used a check from another answer (`sudo -n uptime 2>&1|grep "load"|wc -l`), and this seems to work fine on OS X. It's not as elegant, but it works.

Comment: @nwinkler oh, so it actually depends on the output it generates (not the return value), interesting workaround

Comment: @nwinkler but it is as near as possible. Or even better  because `sudo -n` becomes buggy in sudo -V 1.7.9

Answer (score 0):

According to the sudo manual, the sudo session is determined according to the time stamp file (`/usr/lib/sudo/<username>`), so you may be able to figure out how much time is left by checking the date/time of the time stamp file. However, in my system, the time stamp file is in fact a directory, and there are three files with cryptic content in them (and also some weird time stamps, but `/usr/lib/sudo/<username>` seemed to have a timestamp that coincided with the time I gave sudo my password. I think `/usr/lib/sudo/<username>/0` has the time stamp of the most recent `sudo` execution.

Comment: On my system, the timestamp files are in a directory which can't be read without using sudo, which prompts for a password and thus wouldn't work for the OP's needs.

Comment: Good point. I didn't check ownership of these files. You are right, it would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**

Acording to Bugzilla sudo Bug ID=590 the call to `sudo -n true 2&>/dev/null ; echo $?` will become buggy around `sudo -V 1.7.10`

Read Bugzilla [here](http://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=590"Bug ID=590")

Answer (score 0):

At least on sudo 1.8.21p2, this approach works fine:

```
if sudo -vn 2> /dev/null; then
    echo "You have an active sudo session"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably extreme overkill by most people's standard, but here is the (posixly correct) function I use to check if `sudo` is unlocked (the function will not waste its time if the user running it is `root`, as there is no need to unlock `sudo`):

```
#!/bin/sh

_unlock_sudo() {
    if [ "$USER" != 'root' ]; then
        if ! sudo -n -- true 2>/dev/null; then
            printf '\n'
            printf 'Enter password for sudo user "%s":\n' "$USER"
            while ! sudo -- true; do
                printf '\n'
                while true; do
                    printf 'Slow your roll. Try to enter password again? [Y/n]: '
                    read -r answer
                    case "$answer" in
                        ''|y|Y|yes|Yes|YES)
                            printf '\n'
                            printf 'Enter password for sudo user "%s":\n' "$USER"
                            break
                            ;;
                        n|N|no|No|NO)
                            printf '\n'
                            printf 'OK. Exiting...\n'
                            exit 1
                            ;;
                        *)
                            printf 'Please enter a valid option...\n'
                            printf '\n'
                            ;;
                    esac
                done
            done
        fi
    fi
}

_unlock_sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but I have a solution that **does not require the `-s` flag**, and does not require temperamental string operations.

A good solution might be to exploit the fact that an unauthenticated `sudo` call hangs for a long time.

`sudo date` will return pretty much instantly if authenticated, but will hang if not.

The `timeout` command is placed before another command to limit how long it takes to execute, and exits with code `124` if it cuts the execution of the inner command short. You can check the exit code of the last command with `echo $?`

With that in mind...

```
timeout .1s sudo date
EXITCODE=$?
```

Now test if $EXITCODE is 127 or not and you have your answer :)

Answer (score -1):

simple answer ...

```
sudo echo
isSudo=$?
if [[ "$isSudo" -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "This script must be run by root or a sudo'er"
  echo
  exit 1
fi

# do stuff

exit 0
```

Comment: This will prompt for a password, if the user doesn't already have an active sudo session

Answer (score -2):

How about the man page

```
man sudo
```

List your available commands:

```
sudo -l
```

sudo itself has no time or date limits... see:

```
man sudo
man sudoers
```

Comment: sudo -l gives me a password prompt.  I need it to tell me I have no active sudo session.

Comment: sudo status times out, but you're correct if you mean that it doesn't have a schedule feature.

Comment: Yes - it times out - but no schedule.