# trying to install Astromenace on my linux mint 14 cinnamon pc

Tags: linux, bash, installation, terminal

so i am following this tutorial as it is the only one i can find and any that i can find are the same as this one:

http://linuxg.net/games-on-linux-how-to-install-astromenace-on-ubuntu-and-fedora/

but when i type in the first command i gives me this

```
myname@myname-System-Product-Name ~ $ sudo wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | apt-key add -
[sudo] password for myname: ERROR: This command can only be used by root.
```

Comment: Does your user account have sudo privileges? Can you [check if you do](http://superuser.com/q/195781/196392)?

Comment: yes, im the admin and it does becouse i use terminal and commands that use sudo all the time

Answer (score 0):

First go to System-Administration-Software Sources, Third-Party Software tab, Add:
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu saucy-getdeb games

Change ubuntu and saucy into the respective distribution and kernel of your linux.

source: http://www.playdeb.net/updates/ubuntu/9.04/