# Why does sudo -n on Mac OS X always return 0?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, sudo

It looks like `sudo -n` on Mac OS X (10.10.3) always returns 0 as a return code.

So something like this will always show 0, regardless of whether the user has authenticated with his password first:

```
sudo -n true &> /dev/null ; echo $?
```

In the case that the user does not have a valid sudo session, I would expect to see 1 as an exit code, but on OS X, it always returns 0.

I'm asking since I've seen this pattern suggested to check for sudo access, e.g. here: https://superuser.com/a/587876/119764

What's the *official* (???) behavior of `sudo -n`? Does it differ by version or OS, or am I missing something?

Comment: My first reaction is "Of course behaviour may differ by OS." The GNU folks and the BSD folks are under no obligation to agree with each other. The "official" answer will have to be: check the man pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. Referring to the man page,

> Otherwise, sudo quits with an exit value of 1
>   if there is a configuration/permission problem
>   or if sudo cannot execute the given command. 
>   In the latter case the error string is printed to stderr. 
>   If sudo cannot stat(2) one or more entries in the user's PATH
>   an error is printed on stderr.  (If the directory does not exist
>   or if it is not really a directory,
>   the entry is ignored and no error is printed.) 
>   This should not happen under normal circumstances. 
>   The most common reason for stat(2) to return "permission denied"
>   is if you are running an automounter
>   and one of the directories in your PATH
>   is on a machine that is currently unreachable.

So it seems to be a bug in OS X.

Comment: @G-Man @Basuke Its a bug in `sudo` not OSX ;) see my answer below

Comment: I am using `port` because of things like that. So I could install `sudo -V 1.8.13` on ` OSX 10.6.8` and use `sudo -n true` without problems.

Comment: Apple finally fixed this bug on 10.10.5 update with bundling sudo of version "1.7.10p9".

Answer (score 2):

After reading sudo manpage again and again I checked Bugzilla [here](http://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=590). This behaviour of sudo is a bug which appeared in 1.7.10 after merging from a 1.8 branch.

If you want to use `sudo -n command &>/dev/null ; echo $?` to check your 'privileges' make sure, you have sudo version 1.7.9b1 and earlier.